# Create an non functional imageview just for visibility

Tags: iphone, ios, math, touch, xcode4.6.3

My app has a circle which is divided into 12 equal pies i.e 1 pie for each 1 hour slab.I need to have a specific tap gesture function for each pie so i thought of assigning a specific colour code to each pie so that i can detect the colour as to where the user has tapped according to the colour of the pie.

So first i need you to help me to detect the colour code on each click. Second I need help with a non functional imageview over those 12 pies so that the user is not able to see those 12 different colours of the pies and only see 1 circle with single colour but tap gestures should always be performed on those 12 pies beneath my 1 coloured circle.Lastly I also need help with the scrolls.

I have Implemented segmented scrollviews in my app so that if user taps from left to right then a new segment gets displayed and vice-versa.The app has only 2 segmented scroll views.One for adding text in those pies on click and other for displaying text in those pies on click.
I am available on teamviewer and skype both so any way of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have implemented the 2 segmented scrolls and they are totally functional.I have the 12 pies of circle right now and i want to implement tap gesture on each pie according to the colour code.I have tried translating a pie on the click of a button and its working fine but i want the translation of pie on click of the pie and not click of a button.

Comment: Why -2 guys? You should have a look on that app and you will know that getting the colour code to perform specific gesture is possibly the best thing that can be done to that app.

Comment: Why do you need to detect the colour? Simple look at the angle of the line connecting the touch location and the centre of the circle (given by `atan2(centre.y - touch.y, centre.x - touch.x)`), and you'll know which segment you are in.

Comment: then also i need to put a line below my imageview(image that the user will see)
Both of these are two different ways of detect the the segment in which the user tapped.What's wrong with my logic?Still didn't get what was better in that logic.....Sorry if i am wrong

Comment: Why would you need a line below the `UIImageView`? Simply check if the touch distance form the centre of the circle is less than the radius of the circle. If it is, check the angle to verify the segment the user touched. Otherwise, assume the touch is for the other thing. This way, you don't have to use colour at all, which will make it easier for you.

Comment: Oh I got your point now....Just thought about it.
+1 for your comment but i still need something to resize the below pies as the user touch in that segment.The pie that needs resizing is the pie below the circle which the user is seeing.Both are of different colours.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1u5bhj
check this screen plz....i want the "staff meeting "pie to hide when the user taps it and it should show when the user touches that circle from 1'o clock to 2'o clock.....did u get me now?

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it is a single massive paragraph, containing three separate questions, with no evidence of what you've already tried. Try splitting this into three separate questions, and include some of the research you've already done or code you've already written. At the moment this is just asking someone else to write your code for you.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for providing me a reason for the downvote.And thanks msgambel for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you have 2 concentric circle with different radii. To achieve the affect you are looking for, you simply need to check the angle of the line between the users touch and the centre of the circles. Then, you simply check the length of the line to see which circle you are in. Try:

```
// Find the pie segment you are in. Angle in radians.
float angle = atan2(centre.y - touch.y, centre.x - touch.x))

// Use the angle to figure out which segment the user tapped in. You'll have to
// figure out the angles for the 12 segments on your own!
if(angle > 2.7489 || angle < -2.7489){

}

// Compute the length of the line.
float dx = centre.x - touch.x;
float dy = centre.y - touch.y;
float length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

// Check if the user touched the inner circle.
if(length <= radius1){

}
// Check if the user touched the outer circle.
else if(length <= radius2){

}
// The user tapped outside both circles.
else{

}
```

From there, you simply add the code in that you need to change the layout of either circle. Hope that Helps!

Comment: can u plz help me up with the angle values for just 1 pie?
like say from 12'o clock to 1'o clock

Comment: Read the documentation on radians and `atan2`, and you'll figure it out.